# QtPainter Error Paint device returned engine ==0, type 3 ,Painter not active

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I'm trying to paint some points of my image and I don't know why it doesn't work. I have defined a QImage and I want to modify some points.

```
QImage *cou= new QImage(height,largeur,QImage::Format_Mono);
    cou->fill(1);
    QPainter *fig=new QPainter (cou);
    for (i=0;i<size_;i++)
    {
        fig-> drawPoint(floor(propa[i]),nbmax[i]);
    }
```

When I execute the code I obtain

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
```

and in the following lines:

```
QPainter::drawPoints: Painter not active
```

Comment: Have you checked if a null image is returned? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#isNull

Comment: Also check the size of `cou`, `qDebug() << cou->size();`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
```

The error means that the image you're trying to paint is a null image. Use `isNull` on `cou`to check this.
The cause of image being null may be the wrong `height` and `largeur` params when the image is constructed, or you're out of memory

Answer (score 2):

```
QPaintEngine* eng = cou->painterEngine();
if(eng) {
//   create QPainter ...
}
```

Comment: Perhaps some explanation to your answer would be helpful for OP and future visitors of this page?